# Looking for an adverb/adjective describing a person that gave up on something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Considering the context:

> She was stating the obvious, looking **>insert descriptive adverb<**

I am looking for an adverb/adjective that could describe like "looking like she gave up".

The closest ones I could come up with was **dejected*ly*** and **lifeless*ly***. Is there a word, that can describe exactly like stated above?

EDIT: I'm not looking for *Depressed/Disappointed* kind of meaning, it's more like: stuff like that happened before, so she is **tired of that repetition**/*gave up on caring about it*.

Comment: Your question says you are looking for an adverb. Did you mean an adjective?

Comment: @TommyTran My initial train of thought was a descriptive words with -ly at the end, adverbs. But maybe there would be a fitting adjective for it, I'll edit the question.

Comment: "She was stating the obvious, looking [BLANK]." An adjective fits here. An adverb would not be grammatical here. Unless you mean to say "She was stating the obvious, looking [BLANK] at John." _Looking dejectedly at John_ would work. _Looking dejectedly_ would not. In this instance, "looking" functions as a linking verb that connects "she" to a word that would be able to modify it or redescribe it in some way. Adverbs can't modify nouns, which is why I asked. If you're asking for an adverb, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @TommyTran Added extra context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She looks **resigned**:

> Having accepted something unpleasant that one cannot do anything about.
>   *‘Akiko glances at it and looks resigned, then hopeful.’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resigned)</sub>

Also note it has an adverb form: *resignedly*.

Comment: I think this is exactly the word I would be looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

Defeated:

> adjective. having been beaten in a battle or other contest. demoralized and overcome by adversity.

Weary (one can be weary of repetition):

> adjective. feeling or showing tiredness, especially as a result of excessive exertion or lack of sleep.

Answer (score 2):

She looked **beaten**.

> beaten, adj.
> 7. Conquered, defeated.
>
> [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/16614?result=3&rskey=YDEcSp&#:%7E:text=%C2%A07.%20Conquered%2C%20defeated.)

Answer (score 1):

The verb *look* in your example functions as a copula, so it requires an adjective, not an adverb.

That said, what's wrong with *dejected*? It should work in the sentence with the intended meaning. **Dejected** means dispirited, cast down, disappointed (these three could also work, incidentally). Dejected is how one would typically feel after giving up on something.

An alternative is **defeatist**, which suggests that one has given up a fight or contest, usually prematurely so, but it is a bit more specific.

Comment: Thank you, I should add a bit more context. Dejectedly implies more for depressed, disappointed; in my case, it is like - stuff like that happened before, so she was stating the obvious, no longer caring about it. Like tired of this repetition.